# Which mysql collation is good for storing unicode strings?

Tags: mysql, collation, unicode

For all I know it must be `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, but:

```
> create table t1 (f1 varchar(255) collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
> insert into t1 (f1) values ('')
```

And what I get is:

```
ERROR 1366 (22007) at line 1: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\xA2\x84\x82'
    for column 'f1' at row 1
```

The symbol I'm inserting into the database is [this one](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22102/index.htm).

Comment: Context?  What client are you using?

Comment: The commands above I executed in `mysql` client. I ran into the issue when running a `ruby` script. But like I said in my answer, it didn't cross my mind to change connection character set as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with connection character set. After setting it to `utf8mb4`, it succeeded. One way is to add `default-character-set = utf8mb4` to `client` or `mysql` sections of `~/.my.cnf`.

**UPD** Before adding `default-character-set` to `~/.my.cnf` I had:

```
> show variables like 'character_set_%'
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
```

And `insert into t1 (f1) values ('')` gave me:

```
ERROR 1366 (22007) at line 1: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\xA2\x84\x82'
    for column 'f1' at row 1
```

After adding `default-character-set = utf8mb4` I have:

```
> show variables like 'character_set_%'
character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
```

And `insert into t1 (f1) values ('')` succeeds.

Comment: Is that sufficient?  Or do you still have problems?

Comment: Actually yes. And now that I look at the title, the answer seems a bit off. But for all I know `utf8mb4` is generally the best option, when you deal with all kinds of characters. So the answer can be read between the lines. Or feel free to give yours.

Comment: I worry that a single setting in my.cnf may not suffice.

Comment: From my experience it will. There are two mandatory things to do: 1) change column character set, 2) change connection character set. What else do you think is needed?

Comment: 3 settings by client (what `SET NAMES` does); html `meta`.  But I will experiment with your single-setting solution.  See [Best Practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored).

Comment: First, I wasn't talking about web apps. All experimenting I did in console. And I ran into the issue with again console script written in ruby, which writes data to database. As for `SET NAMES`, that's exactly what `default-character-set` does for console clients. I doubt if, e.g., ruby gems respect what's in `~/.my.cnf`.

Comment: aghhh...Thank you! Why it's not mentioned more in docs. Spent too much time on this